# Schwarz Inequality?

Tags: inequality

Is the following inequality correct $$\bigl|\sum_i a_i h_i\bigl|^2 \leq \sum_i |a_i|^2 |h_i|^2 $$

I am assuming it is using the triangle inequality, if yes can someone explain to me intuitvely why? and when is it met with equality?

Comment: @graydad thanks, so is the above inequality not correct?

Comment: @KittyL Looks wrong to me. Try $a_i = h_i = 1$ with $n=2$. The left side should equal $4$ while the right side equals $2$.

Comment: @ graydad: My bad. Didn't look carefully. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false, and your inequality is not the Schwarz inequality. Let $n=2$ and set $a_i = h_i = 1$. Then your inequality says $$\left|\sum_{i=1}^21\right|^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^21 \\ \implies (1+1)^2 \leq 1+1$$ The Schwarz inequality says $$\left|\sum_{i=1}^n a_i h_i\right|^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \left|a_i\right|^2 \sum_{i=1}^n \left|h_i\right|^2$$ or that the square of the sum of all $a_ih_i$ is less than or equal to the sum of all $a_i^2$'s  multiplied by the sum of all $h_i^2$'s. That is not what your inequality is conveying.